# How can I give my programmatically created Google Spreadsheets a Sidebar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

#### Background:

1. I have a **Script Project**, tooled up using [node-google-apps-script](https://github.com/danthareja/node-google-apps-script)
2. I have a Rails app that uses the **Script Project** to create Spreadsheets using the **REST Execution API**. It does this by cloning a template Spreadsheet.
3. My Rails app also occasionally pushes data to the Spreadsheet, using the **REST Execution API**
4. The **Script Project** is published privately using **Publish>Deploy as API Executable...**, and the **Rails App** uses the API Executable ID to talk to it.

The above all works reasonably well, and development is not too onerous.

Now I want the generated spreadsheets to have a sidebar. The alternatives I've discovered so far each seem problematic:

### Alternative 1: Publish private Add-On

I'm aware that I can get my client to make me an admin of their google apps domain, and then I can publish the **Script Project** as a domain-restricted add-on. This alternative seems like it will be onerous both for development & usage:

- add-ons take up to an hour to publish. Publishing a version of the **Script Project** is now *two* manual routines which can't be automated
- as best I can tell, I can't programmatically add the add-on to the spreadsheet. It has to be installed in each spreadsheet before use.

### Alternative 2: Give the Template Spreadsheet a Bound Script

I could give the **Template Spreadsheet** a **Bound Script**. Apparently, that will be copied. **Bound Scripts** can't be tooled with [node-google-apps-script](https://github.com/danthareja/node-google-apps-script), so I will be stuck using copy & paste updating. Updates to the script would require manually updating each existing spreadsheet! However possibly I could make the sidebar a skeleton that pulls its actual content from the **Script Project**.

**Is there a better way?**

Comment: A variant of option2 plus your library is possible. I'll post more details when I get some time here in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you can do is tie all the sidebar creation part of the programming to the library that you have created. In the templated spreadsheet that you use, you should only need to do the following:

1. Add your library to the container bound script using the Project Key of the library script.
2. Add a simple onOpen function to create a menu that then calls the library create sidebar function.
3. Since all of the server side functions that might be called by the sidebar will be contained in the library, you will need to add a function handler that calls the correct function in your library to pass off to the sidebar when using `google.script.run` For example:

Library Functions:

```
function getSomeNum() {
  return 3;
}

function doSomething(e) {
  return e.num * 2;
}

var runFunction = {
  getSomeNum : getSomeNum,
  doSomething : doSomething
};

function runHandler(functionName, parameters) {
  return runFunction[functionName](parameters);
}
```

Container Bound Handler:

```
function runHandler(functionName, parameters) {
  return MyLibraryIdentifier.runHandler(functionName, parameters);
}
```

Example google.script.run call from sidebar:

```
function onLoad() {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(processNum)
    .runHandler("getSomeNum");
}

function processNum(num) {
  var event = {
    num : num
  };

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler( function(retNum) { alert(retNum); } )
    .runHandler("doSomething", event);
}
```

Keep in mind that any user that needs to utilize this sidebar must at least have view access to the library. What I ended up doing was deploying as an API Executable for anyone and then setting the sharing of the script to public-view only, but must have link. It's the only thing that seemed to work to get it to multiple users.

Another downside is when updating the code of the library, the container bound scripts will not be updated unless you change the library version they are utilizing. Meaning the user would have to actively look for newer library versions. When Updating the API executable, the menu gives you the impression that you can just update the current version, but I haven't had any luck in to actually getting it to reflect the changes (perhaps I just wasn't patient enough).

This should at least get you a base line of where to begin your testing.

Comment: This looks excellent, thanks very much. I will try it later today and give feedback. It sucks that you have to deploy API executable for anyone, but I had a feeling I would end up having to do that at some point. I will handle the library id by writing it to the spreadsheet, and giving my rails app the ability to push out a version to all spreadsheets. I also do this to give spreadsheets an auth token so a given spreadsheet can only affect data in the rails app that is related to it.

Comment: finally got a chance to work on this. It works as described, but there are a couple issues: somewhat difficult to debug, because you can't access the logs of bound script handlers (except to run them manually). I tried to use [BetterLog](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog) to make life easier, but GAPPS won't let me use BetterLog in onOpen/onInstall, even indirectly thru my library. It's fine in handlers. Second, its **quite slow** -- up to 4 seconds to run a handler.

Comment: The runFunction struct is unnecessary; can just use `this[functionName]`

Comment: Although perhaps it is better to explicitly define what functions clientside handlers can access.

Comment: Libraries traditionally run slower in GAS, for my particular use, speed wasn't a deciding factor. Although I didn't really recognize that much of a difference.